# How to set margin with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing this:

```
var sId=id.toString();
var index=sId.substring(3);
var mrg=index*221;
var el=$(id);
el.css('margin-left',mrg+'px'); and el.css('marginLeft',mrg+'px');
```

el is the element i want to set the margin to (correctly retrieved) and mrg is the value of the new margin

If i do $`('#test1').css('margin-left',200);` or `$('#test1').css('marginLeft',200);` it works in both ways, it's something wrong with the way i set the property.

The correct way is var `el=$('#'+id);`

Comment: Can you post the relevant code in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: If that's the case, do an alert on mrg and see what value is being returned

Answer (score 80, accepted):

try

```
el.css('margin-left',mrg+'px');
```

Answer (score 18):

Set it with a px value. Changing the code like below should work

```
el.css('marginLeft', mrg + 'px');
```