# How to set margin for every element inside a div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've looked: [How to set margin with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314532/how-to-set-margin-with-jquery)

This is what I am trying:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content").each(function (el) {
        el.css('margin', '0px');
    })
});
```

This isn't working though; right now I have to set the margin to zero in the style sheet.

Comment: You **should** be using CSS to change styles. JS should be used to change *classes*.

Comment: I totally agree, the trouble is that some tags, when inside my 'content' div, create odd margins that make the 'content' div move. To avoid this, I remove the margin. However, because I cannot anticipate every tag that will have margin applied to it, I remove it dynamically through jQuery. If I can do this through CSS I would much rather do so.

Comment: In fact, I just tried using the wildcard in my CSS and it works without having to be specific with my selector! Awesome!

Comment: I'm pretty certain the problem you're having is [margin-collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins), but it sounds like you should read up on your [selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pattern-matching) as well.

Comment: Ok, will do. I'm new to both web development, so I'm kinda crash coursing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".content *").css('margin', '0px');
});
```

The problem is you are setting the margin on the element itself, and not on its children.
The selector `.content *` means "anything inside an element with class content". (Anything, and not just direct children.)

Comment: This is what I thought he meant too. +1

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I will mark as correct in 8 minutes :D

Comment: Take your time. The correct answer is not even the first to fix your problem, but the best to the question you wrote. Maybe others will provide an even better one. :)

Answer (score 4):

[`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) already iterates over every element:

```
$('.content').css('margin', '0');
```

The issue you're having is that [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) passes the dom node itself to the function, but it's the second parameter:

```
$('.content').each(function (i, ele) {
    $(ele).css('margin', '0');
    //the context is also set to the element
    $(this).css('margin', '0');
});
```

---

After re-reading your question, it looks like you've chosen the wrong selector, I can't tell if you want all *children* or all *descendants*, the selector should be:

```
$('.content > *')
```

-or-

```
$('.content *')
```

respectively